# valgrind shows memory leak in the simplest tensorflow python program

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-leaks, valgrind

I got recently stuck on the problem of linearly increasing ram usage in tensorflow estimator evaluator with my custom dataset op (it happens with TextLineDatasetOp as well but to a lesser extent because there is no large memory object). So I decided to use valgrind to see where memory leak could potentially occur.

After eliminating all the obvious memory leak sources and confirmed that a c++ unit test had no leak according to valgrind, I switched to testing with python program directly. What came out was quite shocking as my simple python unit test of the custom op gave a ton of definitely lost bytes. Then I tried the following simplest cases:

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; \
s = tf.Session(); s.run(tf.constant(1)); s.close()'
```

and got this horrible mess

```
==82484== LEAK SUMMARY:
==82484==    definitely lost: 222,551 bytes in 876 blocks
==82484==    indirectly lost: 159,625 bytes in 1,285 blocks
==82484==      possibly lost: 6,896,204 bytes in 44,294 blocks
==82484==    still reachable: 1,507,983,981 bytes in 1,012,356 blocks
==82484==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==82484==                         stdstring          : 2,782,487 bytes in 70,335 blocks
==82484==                         newarray           : 2,976 bytes in 5 blocks
==82484==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==82484== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
```

As a baseline, I also tried:

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes python -c 'print(1)'
```

and things looked much better

```
==87404== LEAK SUMMARY:
==87404==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==87404==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==87404==      possibly lost: 364,295 bytes in 2,377 blocks
==87404==    still reachable: 573,861 bytes in 5,256 blocks
==87404==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Should I take valgrind seriously in either case (e.g., do I have to build tensorflow and even python from source under debug/valgrind-friendly mode)? Thanks.

My tensorflow version is 1.12.0, installed via pip3.6. My OS is Centos 7. I suspect the above can be reproduced on a variety of environments.

Comment: Hello, have you tried with Python's source repository Misc/ valgrind supp file? https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Misc/valgrind-python.supp

Comment: @myselfhimself no I haven't. Does this merely suppress warnings?

Comment: It should but for Python core warnings, not Tensorflow-related warnings